# Ubuntu doesn’t turn off displays after sleep

Tags: multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card, ubuntu-18.04

My setup is using original nvidia drivers and 1080 gtx connected to two 4K Dell (U2718Q) monitors.

If I configure power management of both monitors through xset, then I can turn off ether of them and both of them will be correctly turned off.

However, whenever I put my Ubuntu to sleep, both monitors would correctly show that they both have lost signal, then turn off their backlights.

In a few next monents comes the unexpected: sometimes, either one of them or both, will turn on their backlights and keep showing this empty, supposedly black image (no “no signal” is shown). Imagine an LCD screen with full backlight but only a black image is rendered?

I have already tried xset’ing them to be off before putting my computer to sleep with no luck.

Any ideas which of the components may be responsible for it?

Comment: Wow, I am having similar issue, although with 1 monitor. GTX 1070 with a 4K Dell U2720q.  I first had one that worked properly, but it had problems with random lines appearing. I received a replacement from Dell, but now the monitor goes to backlighted black instead of sleep when the pc goes into real sleep. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Are you on Linux? I’ve just assumed it was a driver issue, but now that you reminded me I also have a laptop now that I use with both of these monitors too, and the problem does not manifest itself. The laptop is Dell XPS 13 and it uses intel UHD graphics (but is also Ubuntu)

Comment: Yes, I am on Ubuntu 20.04. I tried several drivers 440, 450 to no avail.

Comment: I am hoping that NVidia will finally release their open-sourced drivers (or open-source power management for nouveau drivers) so that I could switch to nouveau.

Actually I just checked and apparently Nouveau should now support Tesla GPUs (ar at least 16xx series) so I'll try switching to that soon enough

Comment: I got it working now, all I had to do was to enable deep sleep in my bios. Now my videocard's LEDs are also turning off, so probably without that setting the videocard was not powered down completely, and thus giving a signal or something that interfered. Tested it now a few times, and my screen goes really into sleep mode and stays. I still use the NVIDIA driver.